# import html file for common header can't read <head> and relative javascript and css sources

Tags: php, html, css, import, include

This is my project structure:

[image: Screenshot of project structure]

I would like to import the common header (*top.html*) in all new pages, but I don't know why when I include *top.html*, it doesn't import head's link with CSS and JS source (external).

If I run directly *top.html*, it works perfectly and can read CSS and JS source.

```
# I used this path for include
include '../app/views/common/top.html';
```

Comment: update your question and add  your code  ..

Comment: The include function won't fix your relative paths to assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because of incorrect path.

For example, inside top.html you are using relative path like

```
<script src="/script.js" />
```

Which will automatically include SITE_URL+"app/views/common/script.js". Here this is correct path.

but after using

```
include '../app/views/common/top.html'
```

it will search file script.js on "/app/views/home/" path which is now incorrect path.

To solve this issue you can define path for js and css file in php and should use absolute path.

For Example:

```
<script src="<?=SITE_PUBLIC_PATH?>/script.js" />
```

Comment: you got a point, the problem were the path for source js and css of the  top.html. 
I fixed it with tag <base> in the <head> of top.html
<base href=" http://localhost/TWeb/app/views/common/" >